# Set heuristic emphasis to aggressive in pyscipopt

Tags: python, scip

I would like to make scip use heuristics more aggressively via pyscipopt.
There is

```
model.setRealParam('limits/gap', 0.01)
```

and I am looking for something similar. To look at all parameters it is suggested to use

```
model.writeParams('default.set', onlychanged=False)
```

but in the resulting default.set a search for "emphasis" only leads to some precedence options.
(How) Can I specify aggressive heuristics in pyscipopt?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the option to use:

`model.setHeuristics(SCIP_PARAMSETTING.AGGRESSIVE)`

The emphasis settings in SCIP are not just one setting, but each emphasis setting is a collection of individual parameters.